# Does express for node.js have a .request()

Tags: node.js, express, last.fm

I'm trying to get a response from an outside url using the below code, but im having no luck. Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong and give any pointers they think could be helpful.

```
var express = require('express'),
              require('events');

var app = express.createServer();

app.request({
    host: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com",
    port: 80,
    method: "GET",
    path: "/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=bandname&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026"
}).on('response',function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you can.  You could just use the built-in request function (see [this](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.5/api/http.html#http.request):

From the website:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/upload',
    method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

It's pretty easy and you can still use it in your existing code...

Sometimes frameworks don't have solutions for everything... the documentation is your friend.

Comment: This seems to be working; however, im getting a 404 response... any clue why this could be happening?

Comment: 404 means your URL is bad. See the [HTTP Response code specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: Even when you copy and paste the code?  You will need a req.end().  Change 'method' to 'GET' and change path to '/' or something.  Once you get that working, you should be good to go.

Comment: When i copy/paste this into its own file and run it, it works fine. There must be something else going on within my script.

Comment: If you can't figure it out, you could open another question. It's probably just a type-o though...